# Usages of external structures without a definition

Tags: c, struct, types, compilation, linker

For the sake of example:

file2.c

```
struct myStruct {
  int a;
} A;
```

file1.c

```
extern struct myStruct A;

int main (void) {

}
```

Compiled using `gcc file1.c file2.c`.

- Is this a valid way of using the global variable `A` in `file1.c` if it is not necessary that we be privy to the internal details (example: function calls only -- such as with a `FILE *`?
- Is the only time a definition (such as the same as that in `file1.c`) is necessary when we manipulate the internal details?
- Is there anything to be said of if these definitions are different (I've noticed it uses the one in the same translation unit -- but is this standard-conformant)?

Previous structure questions do not cover the topic of not including the definition -- only how to do so correctly (in a header file, same in all files that use the structure)

Comment: Try actually using `A` in file1.c

Comment: You may form _pointers_ to `struct myStruct`s (like `&A`) in `file1.c`. That's all you can do.

Answer (score 2):

> - Is this a valid way of using the global variable `A` in `file1.c` if it is not necessary that we be privy to the internal details
>   (example: function calls only -- such as with a `FILE *`?

Yes.  But there are not many things you can do with `A` at any point where its type is incomplete.  Obtaining its address is the main one I can think of.

Note that using a pointer to `A` is not the same thing as using `A` itself.

> - Is the only time a definition (such as the same as that in `file1.c`) is necessary when we manipulate the internal details?

No. You also need the definition if you want to

- define an object of that type or an array with that element type;
- compute the size of the type or an instance of the type via the `sizeof` operator; or
- define a structure or union type that has a member of the type in question.

I may be missing something.

> - Is there anything to be said of if these definitions are different (I've noticed it uses the one in the same translation unit -- but is
>   this standard-conformant)?

If different declarations of the same object specify incompatible types for it then translator and program behavior is undefined.  For unqualified structure types declared in different translation units, "compatible" means:

- if either type is declared with a tag, then both are declared with the same tag;
- the two types have the same number of members, with the same names, in the same order, and corresponding members have compatible types.

Usually, this compatibility requirement is satisfied by declaring the type in a header that all files wanting to use it `#include` -- this avoids the opportunity to introduce incompatibile versions of the type.

Comment: So if I have two translation units, oblivious of each other, which are linked together, can I have a `struct buf` in both with different definitions, and they each use their own `struct buf`?

Comment: @user129393192, **TLDR: yes**.  Neither type definitions nor struct tags have linkage.  Those of one TU are not accessible in any way in other TUs.  That's one of the reasons that spec focuses on *compatible* types rather than insisting on *the same* type for various things. Different TUs declaring types with the same name or tag is utterly routine -- that's often one of the things that `#include`ing headers accomplishes.  There is no fundamental requirement that they do so compatibly, but there are often reasons for wanting that, hence, again, headers.

Answer (score 1):

- Is this a valid way of using the global variable `A` in `file1.c` if it is not necessary that we be privy to the internal details (example: function calls only -- such as with a `FILE *`?

There is no use of the object `A` in `file1.c`, so `file1.c` does not contain a valid way of using the object `A`.

`extern struct myStruct A;` is a valid declaration of `A`. That is a valid use of the name.

With just that declaration, the object `A` could be referred to in `file1.c` by taking its address, `&A`, and that could be useful for passing the address to routines defined in other files where the definition of `struct myStruct` is visible.

A more common way to use “opaque” types (in `file1.c`, we can see there is a type `struct myStruct` but cannot see through to its definition, so it is “opaque”) is to have `file2.c` provide routines for accessing them, such as:

- A routine `struct myStruct *GetMyStruct(parameters);` that allocates memory for a `struct myStruct` and returns a pointer to it.
- A routine that frees a `struct myStruct`. (Might just call `free` but might be more complicated, such as freeing things that are pointed to from data within `struct myStruct`.)
- Routines that manipulate `struct myStruct` in various ways, such as setting values in it, getting values from it, or using it in further computations.

Functions such as the above are generally preferred over using external object identifiers.

Also, `A` is not a global variable. C does not have any global namespace. For a language to have global names, it means that declaring a name once makes it visible throughout the entire program. C does not have that. You can declare a name with external linkage, and they can be linked together to refer to the same object or function, but there needs to be a declaration in each translation unit that uses the name. That is different from global.

> - Is the only time a definition (such as the same as that in `file1.c`) is necessary when we manipulate the internal details?

For the most part, yes, you need a definition of the type.

Technically, you could use `&A` to get the address of `A`, convert it to an `unsigned char *`, and use the resulting pointer to manipulate the bytes of `A`. So it is possible to manipulate `A` without having a definition for the type `struct myStruct`, but that would not be a normal thing to do.

> - Is there anything to be said of if these definitions are different (I've noticed it uses the one in the same translation unit -- but is this standard-conformant)?

Different how?

Comment: Isn't _"There is no use of `A` in `file1.c`"_ and _"... `&A`, and that could be useful ..."_ a contradiction?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: `&A` is not in `file1.c` now, as shown in the question. Even when it is, that is a reference to the object `A`, not a use of the object `A`.

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking that taking its address is one way of using `A`, but perhaps that's wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I am thinking about whether to elaborate on the distinction between the use of the name `A` and the use of the object `A`. Any source code that contains the identifier `A` might be said to be a use of the name. But it is only a use of the object if it accesses the object. The title does ask about use of external structures, which would be uses of objects, not names.

Comment: Ok, I'm happy with that distinction as it is :-)

Comment: *"You can declare a name with external linkage, and they can be linked together to refer to the same object or function, but there needs to be a declaration in each translation unit that uses the name. That is different from global."*, so what if you have two declarations of a `struct buf` in two translation units, with different definitions, and they each use their own? Would they be colliding in the same namespace?

Comment: @user129393192: As my text notes, identifiers can be linked to refer to the same **object or function**. `struct buf` refers to a type, not an object or function. Identifiers for types do not get linked between C translation units. There are rules for compatibility between structure types in different translation units, but this is not linkage. There is no namespace collision since each translation unit has its own namespaces…

Comment: … If `struct buf` is defined differently in two translation units but used in one unit to access an object of the type from the other unit, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.